# Do I still need to keep my "Submit" or "Search" button?

Tags: forms, search

Many sites now provide a search bar without the buttons, and everyone (?) understands that you press enter afterwards anyway.

Is it beneficial to keep the Search button for this case? Do I gain or lose anything by removing it?

[image]

Comment: My bad, this was already asked. Voted to close. Or should I just delete?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is nearly a duplicate of a question answered earlier today, but I don't know how to close and redirect your question.

#### Keep the search button for the search box

For a long time, now, these have been the Nielssen Norman Group's [published guidelines](http://www.nngroup.com/reports/ecommerce-ux-search-including-faceted-search/) (available for purchase, not free). They sum up as follows:

> - Have an easily identifiable search box in the upper right-hand corner of the page, with an open-text field accompanied by a **Search** button.
> - The search box needs no label. A clear **Search** button next to the field identifies the search for the user and tells them how to execute the search.

A button helps people recognize that there's an additional step to trigger the search action—even if they decide to do this by pressing Enter.

#### Magnifying glass

Versions of this icon [image: Typical icon for Search] are increasingly common. For now, NN/g recommends retaining the button, and has also provided some [supplemental recommendations to help make search more usable](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/magnifying-glass-icon/) for your users. For example, pay attention to the **placement** of the search box.

Given your illustration, above, you might also want to check out the recommendation **against** putting instructions inside the search box in the same article.

Hope that helps you move things forward.